# Jenkinsfile post always directive with multiple steps

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I am wondering if it's possible to use various steps block on inside a post step.

Here's the actual code:

```
pipeline {
agent any
stages {
    stage('Test') {
        steps {
            sh 'bash testing.sh'
        }
    }
}
post {
    always {
        steps {
           sh 'bash cleaning-procedure-1.sh'
        }
        steps {
           sh 'bash cleaning-procedure-2.sh'
        }
        steps {
           sh 'bash general-cleaning.sh'
        }
    }
}

}
```

One of the errors that Jenkins gets:

```
WorkflowScript: 291: Missing required parameter: "delegate" @ line 291, column 13.
               step {
```

Is it possible to create different steps inside a POST - ALWAYS block on Jenkins?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`steps` blocks are not allowed inside a `post` directive. If you want to use the `sh` method, then you can invoke it directly outside of the `steps` scope:

```
post {
  always {
    sh 'bash cleaning-procedure-1.sh'
    sh 'bash cleaning-procedure-2.sh'
    sh 'bash general-cleaning.sh'
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `script` block to have multiple actions, like

```
post {
  always {
    script {
      junit '**/build/junit.xml'
      xunit (tools: [CTest(pattern: '**/build/ctest/**/*.xml')] ...)
    }
  }
}
```